# Button Click event in android tabgroup

Tags: android, listview

I have used a tabHost in my android application. The main ActivityGroup class has a listview. When a listview item is clicked, it displays the details in the same tab. I have used a simple activity class for the detail view. the detail view contains a save button which sves the data and returns to the listview(main) screen.
My problem is that for the first time the save button is pressed it works as expected but if the list item is selected again and in the details view if save button is pressed, the application throws error.

Please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error could be caused by many different things. Check to see if you have implemented your Intent  to switch between activities correctly. Like so...

```
/** Called when the user clicks the save button */
public void save(View view)     {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If this isn't what you were looking for, can you provide some examples of your code?